# Prevent jshint warning "Expected '{' and instead saw 'return'."

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, jshint

This is my first post (so if i've done something wrong please let me know), I've had a look through the forum and through the jshint documentation but haven't been able to find an answer so far.

I've found this post describing a similar problem [Expected "{" and instead saw "return"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40370411/expected-and-instead-saw-return)

I am running the following code through jshint

```
if (!x) return;
```

which is returning the error "Expected '{' and instead saw 'return'"

From the other post I believe this is valid syntax but does anyone know how to configure jshint to ignore it? This is the gruntFile.js I am using

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

  // Project configuration.
  grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
    jshint: {
      files:['./src/*.js','!gruntFile.js'],
      options:{
          "curly": true,
          "eqnull": true,
          "eqeqeq": true,
          "undef": false,
          "esversion": 6,
          "globals":{
            "jQuery": true
           }
       }

    }
  });
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-jshint');
  // Default task(s).
  grunt.registerTask('default', ["jshint"]);

};
```

I'm sure it's something very simple but any help would be great.

Thanks

Comment: "From the other post I believe this is valid syntax" Sure it's valid syntax, but you don't use a linter to check your syntax. Linters are for detecting things that are *valid* code but nonetheless *bad* code because they tend to mask or otherwise invite runtime errors. Omitting curly braces is a perfect example of such code.

Comment: Thanks Jordan. I'll keep that in mind.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[The docs say that `curly`](http://jshint.com/docs/options/#curly), which you set to true, controls this behaviour. Just set it to false to disable it.